# Finite element analysis: How can I find the boundary conditions and settings for the knee joints?

Tags: abaqus, finite-element-analysis, ansys

I am not an expert in finite element models (FEMs), however, I am reading related articles and trying to find the boundary conditions for knee joint including the bone and cartilage.

Does anyone have any suggestion? How can I find the boundary conditions for the knee joint?

If there any platform or an atlas guiding on different material properties, I would really appreciate if you guide me on this or share any information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that's impossible to answer without knowing more about the extent of your model.

If you're modeling a whole leg, and just want to see the relative motion of the upper and lower parts, you can fix all degrees of freedom at the hip joint.

The joint itself is complex. There's contact and relative sliding.  Do you plan to include those effects?

What kind of loading will you apply?  This is potentially a small strain, large rotation problem.  Biology is non-linear.

What materials?  Bone?  Artificial knee?  Muscle?  Skin?  What properties?  What material model (e.g. elastic, incompressible, small or large strain, etc.)?